# How to define groups in adoc files

Tags: jqassistant

After updating to the latest jqassistant snapshot rules from adoc files were read, but for execution I still need to provide an XML file. There is the definition of the (default) group located. How do I define groups (e.g. the default group) via adoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is still an open [issue](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues/184) - I'm currently experimenting how this could look like.